# UI_element is not clickable

Tags: selenium

Below code gives webdriver exception `Element is not clickable`

```
public static void hpLinksClick() throws InterruptedException{      
            UI_GenericMethods.gmValidLogin();
            for(int i=0;i<=Li_WE.size()-1;i++){
                WebElement WEObj=Li_WE.get(i);
                //Thread.sleep(500);
                UI_GenericMethods.gmMouseOverAndClik(WEObj);    
                String linkText=Li_WE.get(i).getText();
                System.out.println(linkText);
                if(linkText.equalsIgnoreCase("More")){
              for(int i1=0;i1<=More_Li.size()-1;i1++){              
                    WebElement we_more=More_Li.get(i1);
                    Thread.sleep(500);                                                         UI_GenericMethods.gmMouseOverAndClik(we_more);                               
           }
     } 
}
    WebElement we_molst=DRIVER_OBJ.findElement(By.linkText("More"));
            UI_GenericMethods.gmMouseOverAndClik(we_molst);
            for(int j=0;j<=More_Litd.size()-1;j++){
                WebElement we_molist=More_Litd.get(j);      
                UI_GenericMethods.gmMouseOverAndClik(we_molist);
                Thread.sleep(1000);                 
                we_molst=DRIVER_OBJ.findElement(By.linkText("More"));                   
                UI_GenericMethods.gmMouseOverAndClik(we_molst);             
                }
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (1019, 62.5). Other element would receive the click: <div style="z-index: 1462358621; height: 553px; width: 100%; display: block; opacity: 0.3;" class="small veil" id="__vtigerjs_dialogbox_olayer__"></div> (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 25 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:06:42'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey @ Amar Nath Yadav as per your error .

please note that you are using correct locator strategy to click on the UI_element but still you are getting error just because the element that you want to click is present inside the DOM but still has not fixed position inside the DOM hence error **Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (1019, 62.5). Other element would receive the click**

so please give some time to that UI element to have a fixed position in the DOM so use like

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that the element is scrolled off the screen (and as a result under something like a header bar), you can try scrolling it back into view like this:

```
private void scrollToElementAndClick(WebElement element) { 
int yScrollPosition = element.getLocation().getY(); 
js.executeScript("window.scroll(0, " + yScrollPosition + ");"); 
element.click(); }
```

if you need you could also add in a static offset (if for example you have a page header that is 200px high and always displayed):

```
public static final int HEADER_OFFSET = 200; 
private void scrollToElementAndClick(WebElement element) { 
int yScrollPosition = element.getLocation().getY() - HEADER-OFFSET; 
js.executeScript("window.scroll(0, " + yScrollPosition + ");"); 
element.click(); 
}
```

You can direct click using JavascriptExecutor (Not recommanded)

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By."Your Locator"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Hope it will help you :)